# Flex Builder - "Data binding will not be able to detect changes when using square bracket operator"

Tags: xml, flexbuilder, arraycollection

I am building an app. The first page has a list generated from a local xml which when you select an room type on that list, it pushes the nodes under the selected item; title page, page image, and a new list of products in that room to another list on that second page.

The page title , and page image comes in great, but only the products list from the first node in the "item_name" list is being pushed from the first item (room_name) from the first page.

An error saying this comes up:
Multiple markers at this line:
-Data binding will not be able to detect changes when using square bracket operator. For Array, please use ArrayCollection.getItemAt() instead.
-Line breakpoint: fob.mxml [line: 35]

I know i will deal with this again as i want to push info from that selection to a third page with info about that item.

**Here's the first page:**
    `

```
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        protected function list_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getDataResult.token = macysmain.getData();
        }

        protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            navigator.pushView(fob, event.target.selectedItem);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
    <macysmain:Macysmain id="macysmain"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Image left="10" right="10" top="10" height="40%" smooth="true" source="assets/visual merc.png"/>
<s:List id="list" left="10" right="10" bottom="10" height="55%"
        change="list_changeHandler(event)"
        creationComplete="list_creationCompleteHandler(event)" fontFamily="_sans" fontSize="35"
        labelField="room_name">
    <s:AsyncListView list="    {TypeUtility.convertToCollection(getDataResult.lastResult.room)}"/>
</s:List>
</s:View>`
```

**Second Page(i put ??? ??? around the line in question:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:macysmain="services.macysmain.*"
    title="{data.room_name}">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            navigator.popView();
        }

        protected function        list_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getDataResult.token = macysmain.getData();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
    <macysmain:Macysmain id="macysmain"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button label="Back" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:actionContent>
<s:List id="list" left="10" right="10" bottom="10" height="55%"
        creationComplete="list_creationCompleteHandler(event)" fontSize="35"
        labelField="item_name">
    ?????????<s:AsyncListView list="    {TypeUtility.convertToCollection(getDataResult.lastResult.room[0].item_list.item)}"/>?????????
</s:List>
<s:Image id="roompic" top="50" width="750" height="325" horizontalCenter="0" smooth="true"
         source="{data.room_image}"/>
</s:View>
```

I am at a very basic level.  Any help you be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about FlexBuilder, but based on the error message I would suggest you edit the troublesome line to this:

```
<s:AsyncListView list="{TypeUtility.convertToCollection(getDataResult.lastResult.room.getItemAt(0).item_list.item)}"/>
```

Comment: Nice.  No more error.  But for some reason, when i click the button in the list on the first page, the title and page image is successfully pushed to the new page.  However the new list on the second page always get its info from the first "rooms" item list.